# not able to set the value for autowired parameter

Tags: spring

I have `datasource` autowired with setters. Trying to return `datasource` value with Bean declaration in Spring javaconfig file. For some reason, it is not identifying and showing the error:

> Property   'dataSource' required

Any idea? Here is my Bean in the javaconfig file:

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DataSource dataSource() {        
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("xyz");
        dataSource.setUsername("xyz");
        dataSource.setPassword("xyz");
        return dataSource;
}
```

and the log trace:

```
Error creating bean with name 'featureStoreSpringJDBC' defined 
in URL [jar:file:/C:home/WEB-INF/lib/ff4j-store-springjdbc.jar!
/org/ff4j/store/FeatureStoreSpringJDBC.class]: 
Initialization of bean  failed; nested exception 
is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException 
Property 'dataSource' is required for bean 'featureStoreSpringJDBC'
```

Comment: please add your bean configuration, and the error stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the attribute `dataSource` is not annotated with the `@Autowired` annotation, as a consequence you must explicitely invoke setter and initialize the FeatureStore in javaconfig.

The reason is you should defined the whole FF4J as a bean in the java config.In version before 1.3 it was autowired but we got issues with spreading of javaConfig.